# Datetimepicker plugin jquery done action

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

I am using [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) jQuery plugin and I want to call a function when the done button is pressed, but I can't find where the handler for the done action is and I can't use the onselect function of the plugin because I have to call the function exactly when the done button is pressed. Can someone help me please? I have tried this but neither works.

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-datepicker-close', function() {
    alert("hello");
});

$('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function(){
    alert("ok");
});
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

That plugin does not appear to have a built in handler for the click of the `Done` button, so you will need to delegate an event handler to it:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-datepicker-close', function(e) {
    // do your thing...
});
```